# Add tag "noscript" in HEAD for CSS files ( Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, css, optimization, head

I want to add tag "noscript" in head.

```
 <head><noscript id="deferred-styles">
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://dev.magento2.com/magento2/pub/static/frontend/Magento/xtheme/en_US/mage/css1.css" />
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://dev.magento2.com/magento2/pub/static/frontend/Magento/xtheme/en_US/mage/css2.css" />          
</noscript></head>
```

I have tried with below xml(default_head_blocks.xml) code but not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configura`enter code here`tion.xsd">
<head>      
<noscript id="deferred-styles">
    <css src="css/css1.css" order="1" />
    <css src="font-awesome/css/css2.css" order="2" />
</noscript>     
</head>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add scripts from admin area.

Navigate  **Admin -> Content -> Design -> Configuration -> [your theme] -> HTML Head**.

In this section you can add your scripts.

Comment: how can I forget this way ..(stupidity) :-( +1.

Comment: Easiest way ;) Make a use of native M2 functionality :)

Comment: but my few more css files are coming from another part then how to add tag for that.

Comment: Whatever you add in there will be included before head closing tag in page HTML. So it will be included in all the pages.